# toggle few set of classes and save it via HTML local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I put together a code will allow me to toggle a class and save it in local storage.

Now I need to add 2 more classes to be toggled and be saved in the same manner.
I don't know how to iterate properly with the code and the DOM to achieve this.

This is my "semi-working" example:
http://jsbin.com/nimekebura/1/edit?html,css,js,output

HTML:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bar-toggle">toggle and save state</a>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 //retrieve current state
 $('.container').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

    /* Toggle */
    $('.bar-toggle').on('click',function(){

     // set 1 localstorage values are always strings (no booleans)  
       if (localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle" ) {
          $(".container").toggleClass("with_toggle", true );
          localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";

       } else {
          $(".container").toggleClass("with_toggle", false );
          localStorage.toggled = "";
       }


    });
```

I need to add and toggle another 2 classes to each .box class already in the code.

so the code would toggle like this:

```
<div class="container with_toggle">
  <div class="box multi box_toggled"></div>
  <div class="box multi box_toggled"></div>
</div>
```

what would be the best code practice to achieve the above?

Comment: The `localStorage` object is not meant to be extended with new keys like `toggled`. If you want to add a new item, you use `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: @RedMercury hmm then how would I refactor the code? I just have no idea. would you be able to refactor it and help me also with adding the two extra toggle classes I need please? Ive been working on this for a long time now and I just keep failing. so frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet. I hope, This will help you

[image]

```js
//retrieve current state
if (localStorage.toggled!='') {
 $('.container').toggleClass('with_'+localStorage.toggled);
 $('.box').toggleClass('multi box_'+localStorage.toggled);
}

/* Toggle */
$('.bar-toggle').on('click',function(){
 // set 1 localstorage values are always strings (no booleans)  
  if (localStorage.toggled != "toggle" ) {
    $(".container").toggleClass("with_toggle", true );
    $(".box").toggleClass("multi box_toggle", true );
    localStorage.toggled = "toggle";

  } else {
    $(".container").toggleClass("with_toggle", false );
    $(".box").toggleClass("multi box_toggle", false );
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }
});
```

```css
.container{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #ccc;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
}
.with_toggle{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px orange;
}
.box{
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}
.box_toggle{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bar-toggle">Toggle &amp; Save state</a>
<br><br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

if you just need to iterate through each div container and add classes.

```
$('.container').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('with_toggle');
  $(this).find('.box').addClass('multi box_toggled');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP mentions toggling on click and saving the value to local storage; neither of which you address in your answer.

Comment: "the values is already getting saved with my code above, what I need to do is to add two more classes to the .box" this is what he said in the comment above.